# Create a form solely for inputting data?

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to create a form for a database in MS Access, that will be used solely to allow users to input data into the database. However, all the options I have found do not allow for this, they all provide navigation buttons that allow users to navigate to data that has already been entered into the forms that are related to them. How can I create a form to just allow users to input data without allowing them to look over more of the information held in the form's related table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter design mode on your entry form, open up your properties window and select the form object. You should find a property called "Data Entry" which you should set to "Yes." This removes the link to all data from the related table and will only display blank controls. You can then have your user enter data directly into the form. I believe the default adds the data to the table when they exit the last control in the tab order.

There are also options in the same properties pane for the form that allow you to switch off the record navigation buttons.